# How SAML 2.0 SSO can be done by Service provider for an existing IDP?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

One of the IDP who has setup on SAML 2.0 . How as an SERVICE PROVIDER  I should configure the SAML and send them a call back url so that my login page should be called by them

Answer (score 0):

You need a client-side [SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

This will do all the plumbing for you.